# Identifying kits to find instructions, red Ferrari with white mirrors and rear engine?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I am looking for what set number this is. It has Ferrari symbols on it. Any ideas so that I can find instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the red model from [8143-1: Ferrari F430 Challenge 1:17](https://brickset.com/sets/8143-1/Ferrari-F430-Challenge-1-17) without stickers.

[image: set image]

You can find a link to the instructions from the link above.